# Can WebORB "share" a port with another site in IIS?

Tags: iis, port, weborb

I'm using WebORB for .NET and I've had no problems with it running on its default port (2037) in my development environment.

When I deploy it to my staging environment and attempt to access it over the public internet, this port is blocked at many points along the way as it's an uncommon port, and I observe a red WebORB logo with the message "can not connect to messaging server" when I access the WebORB console.

Opening the port is a partial solution, but anyone accessing WebORB's applications will also need to ensure they're not blocking that port... so it's not really a proper solution.

I have managed to get WebORB running on port 443 (which is used for SSL, and therefore almost never blocked), but only if I have no other sites in IIS with a port 443 binding.

This is also unacceptable as I will eventually have another site on the same server with a port 443 binding.

So, my question is: is it possible to run WebORB on port 443 (or 80), when another site in IIS is also bound to that port?

### Update following answer

I'm on Server 2008R2, and therefore IIS7.5, and I'd prefer to run my WebORB website in integrated mode.  The instructions in the first article mention adding a wildcard script map for Isapi.dll - this will only be invoked in classic mode.

I've added all of the entries that the article suggests, and have configured my site to use port 80.  There are other sites bound to port 80 in IIS.

When I navigate to the WebORB console, I'm observing the same behaviour I saw before adding the new RTMPT handlers - a red WebORB logo and no entries appearing in the "Messaging Server" panel.  However, I do see the "Bad request, only RTMPT supported." message when navigating to ~/open/1, and my diagnostics.aspx page looks fine.

In the log I see the following:

> ...
>
> WEBORB INFO:adding child scope for - \root
>
> WEBORB INFO:scope registered - \root
>   WEBORB INFO:WebORB Messaging Server 4.4.0.0 (c) 2003-2010 Midnight Coders, Inc.
>
> WEBORB INFO:is running - False
>
> **WEBORB EXCEPTION:System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
>      at Weborb.Messaging.BaseRTMPServer.start()**
>
> WEBORB INFO:shutting down WebORB Message Server
>
> WEBORB INFO:loading type: Weborb.Management.ServiceBrowser.Browser.AssemblyBrowser
>
> ...

Do I need to alter any other config to enable the console to use RTMPT?

Also, given that incoming requests must be over HTTP, is there no way to consider host headers?

Answer (score 0):

what you are asking is whether you can route RTMP connections via port 80 or 443. Since these ports are managed by IIS, the incoming connections **must be** HTTP-based. Your RTMP clients can connect via port 80 or 443 by using RTMPT or RTMPS respectively. In that case, you do not need to "run WebORB on these ports", but instead configure WebORB to use RTMPT or RTMPS. Please see the following doc:

Configuring RTMPT in WebORB: http://www.themidnightcoders.com/fileadmin/docs/dotnet/v4/guide/rtmpt.htm

Configuring RTMPS in WebORB:
http://www.themidnightcoders.com/fileadmin/docs/dotnet/v4/guide/rtmps_support.htm

Hope this helps.

UPDATE: If the goal is to route the management console's traffic via RTMPT, it will not work with the currently released version. The console can dynamically determine the RTMP port, but it will stick to the RTMP protocol and does not have the code to switch to RTMPT. This is something we will look into. 
As for the exception you're getting, it occurs because the port you specified in Global.asax is already taken by some other process.